# Put underbar in edit text android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to put underbar in edit text , previously underbar comes automatically but now i cannot find it now . I have to add it using android : background attribute and make a line shape in drawable , but this also dont work as the stroke appears in the centre of the texts . So how can i get that under bar

**Edit text code**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/line2"
        android:hint="hhkfnvkslnbkfnbkfnbknbdkbnlbkn"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent" />
```

**Stroke**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#0000FF"/>
    <size android:height="100dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Please post your output as an Image here.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view below the EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/underbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/line2"
    android:hint="hhkfnvkslnbkfnbkfnbknbdkbnlbkn"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/underbar"
    style="@style/EditTextLine"
    android:layout_below="@+id/underbar"/>
```

And in your `styles.xml`,

```
<style name="EditTextLine">
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Make sure that the EditText and the View is wrapped in a `RelativeLayout`. You can re-use the same underbar-style below every EditText.